# Open a web page within my fragment through one webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I'm trying to open a web page within my fragment through one webview, but the problem is that I could not and I get that unfortunately has closed the application.

Annex the code with which I'm working.

Any suggestions or help?

Thanks for everything.

.java

```
package com.example.dona1click;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Patrocinadores extends Fragment {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nosotros, container, false);

        String url = "10.1.1.8/dona1clickmobile/index.php";

                // or 
        // WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webview);

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return x;
    }
}
```

log:

```
   07-21 11:04:44.446: D/dalvikvm(1417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 3% free 4816K/4944K, paused 210ms, total 212ms
07-21 11:04:45.336: D/dalvikvm(1417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 3% free 5455K/5568K, paused 204ms, total 204ms
07-21 11:04:45.836: I/ActionBar(1417): null seleccionada.
07-21 11:04:46.146: D/dalvikvm(1417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 2% free 5525K/5628K, paused 202ms, total 207ms
07-21 11:04:46.146: I/dalvikvm-heap(1417): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.669MB for 2304016-byte allocation
07-21 11:04:46.376: D/dalvikvm(1417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 7774K/7880K, paused 227ms, total 227ms
07-21 11:04:49.916: I/Choreographer(1417): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-21 11:04:51.266: I/ActionBar(1417): null deseleccionada.
07-21 11:04:51.266: I/ActionBar(1417): null seleccionada.
07-21 11:04:51.556: D/dalvikvm(1417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2504K, 32% free 5557K/8144K, paused 161ms, total 164ms
07-21 11:04:51.556: I/dalvikvm-heap(1417): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.000MB for 2618896-byte allocation
07-21 11:04:51.646: D/dalvikvm(1417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 25% free 8113K/10704K, paused 93ms, total 93ms
07-21 11:04:52.166: D/AndroidRuntime(1417): Shutting down VM
07-21 11:04:52.176: W/dalvikvm(1417): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a86ba8)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): Process: com.example.dona1click, PID: 1417
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.example.dona1click.Patrocinadores.onCreateView(Patrocinadores.java:26)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-21 11:04:52.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 11:04:54.686: I/Process(1417): Sending signal. PID: 1417 SIG: 9
07-21 11:04:57.496: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 5% free 2809K/2956K, paused 72ms, total 75ms
07-21 11:04:57.496: I/dalvikvm-heap(1443): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.604MB for 1872016-byte allocation
07-21 11:04:57.566: D/dalvikvm(1443): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4636K/4788K, paused 58ms, total 58ms
07-21 11:04:58.296: D/gralloc_goldfish(1443): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your mWebView ever assigned to anything?  It looks like you commented out the code that assigned a webview by calling `findViewById(R.id.my_webview);`.  Though, the variable name is different in that case.

You need to assign mWebView.  Also, there must be a webview in that layout file you're inflating.

Trying to do something with a variable that hasn't been assigned a value is the quickest way to throw a nullPointerException.

```
WebView mWebView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nosotros, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);

    String url = "10.1.1.8/dona1clickmobile/index.php";
    // probably a good idea to check it's not null, to avoid these situations:
    if(mWebView != null){
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    return x;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, it worked perfect. The error was mine, but Your answer is pretty optimal. Thank.